# perl regular expressoin not matching

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file (1.txt) with following information and format:

```
{
  "ip": "X.X.XX.8",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Kuala Terengganu",
  "region": "Terengganu",
  "country": "MY",
  "loc": "5.3302,103.1408",
  "org": "AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider"
}{
  "ip": "X.X.XX.143",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Kuantan",
  "region": "Pahang",
  "country": "MY",
  "loc": "3.8077,103.3260",
  "org": "AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider"
}{
  "ip": "X.X.XXX.76",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Kuching",
  "region": "Sarawak",
  "country": "MY",
  "loc": "1.5310,110.3442",
  "org": "AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider",
  "postal": "93700"
}{
  "ip": "X.X.XX.158",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Seoul",
  "region": "Seoul-t'ukpyolsi",
  "country": "KR",
  "loc": "37.5985,126.9783",
  "org": "AS17839 DreamcityMedia"
}{
  "ip": "XX.XXX.X.87",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Surat",
  "region": "Gujarat",
  "country": "IN",
  "loc": "20.9667,72.9000",
  "org": "AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd."
}{
  "ip": "XXX.XX.XXX.134",
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "city": "Bhandup",
  "region": "Maharashtra",
  "country": "IN",
  "loc": "19.1500,72.9333",
  "org": "AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd."
}{
```

I wrote the following perl code so I can output it to a comma separated file:

```
use FileHandle;
use strict;

main();

sub main() {
    my $line_numbers = "";
    my $num_matches  = 0;
    my $first_match  = "";
    my $count        = 0;

    my $resource_location = "1.txt";

    my $output_fh = FileHandle->new("> 2.txt");

    open(FILE, "<", $resource_location) or die "cannot open < $resource_location: $!";

    my $output_str = "";
    foreach my $line (<FILE>) {
        $count++;
        my ($ip)       = $line =~ /"ip=([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})"/;
        my ($hostname) = $line =~ /"hostname:?([^"\s]+)"/;
        my ($city)     = $line =~ /"city:?([^"\s]+)"/;
        my ($region)   = $line =~ /"region:?([^"\s]+)"/;
        my ($country)  = $line =~ /"country:?([^"\s]+)"/;
        my ($org)      = $line =~ /"org:?([^"\s]+)"/;

        print $output_fh "$ip,$hostname,$city,$region,$country,$org\n";
    }

    print "$count   rows processed\n";

    close FILE;
    $output_fh->close;
}
```

when I run the script all i get is commas:

```
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
,,,,,
```

Expected output:

```
"X.X.XX.8","No Hostname","Kuala Terengganu","Terengganu", "MY","AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider"
"X.X.XX.143","No Hostname","Kuantan","Pahang","MY","AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider"
"X.X.XXX.76","No Hostname","Kuching","Sarawak","MY","AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider"
"X.X.XX.158","No Hostname","Seoul","Seoul-t'ukpyolsi","KR","AS17839 DreamcityMedia"
"XX.XXX.X.87","No Hostname","Surat","Gujarat","IN","AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd."
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That's almost JSON. Just use the JSON module to parse it. Then you can do `$obj->{country}` to get the country.

Comment: Sorry what I was expecting as output is:  

"X.X.XX.8","No Hostname","Kuala Terengganu","Terengganu", "MY","AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider"
"X.X.XX.143","No Hostname","Kuantan","Pahang","MY","AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider"
"X.X.XXX.76","No Hostname","Kuching","Sarawak","MY","AS4788 TM Net, Internet Service Provider"
"X.X.XX.158","No Hostname","Seoul","Seoul-t'ukpyolsi","KR","AS17839 DreamcityMedia"
"XX.XXX.X.87","No Hostname","Surat","Gujarat","IN","AS45528 Tikona Digital Networks Pvt Ltd."

Comment: No, I meant you should use the `JSON` module, like this: `perl -0175 -MJSON -nE'say join ", ", @{JSON::decode_json($_)}{qw|ip hostname city region country org|}}{say "\n$. lines processed"'  < 1.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Ack! It's easier to use an actual JSON parser to parse JSON than trying to hack a fragile, error-prone solution!

Ok, you don't actually have a JSON file, but a bunch of JSON files end-to-end. But that's no problem; JSON::XS's incremental parser (`incr_parse`) can handle that.

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use JSON::XS     qw( );
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $json_parser = JSON::XS->new();
my $csv_formatter = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });

while ( my $file = do { local $/; <> } ) {
   for my $obj ( $json_parser->incr_parse($file) ) {
      my @row = @$obj{qw( ip hostname city region country org )};
      $csv_formatter->print(\*STDOUT, \@row);
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
myparser.pl input.json >output.csv
```

Comment: Why don't you use the just the `JSON` module? It falls back to `JSON::PP` if `JSON::XS` isn't installed and also has a `incr_parse` method.

Comment: @Patrick J. S., Why would I want to risk being defaulted to JSON::PP?

Comment: People sometimes have a hassle with installing modules (send the sysadmin a email, get it approved by some supervisors…) and `JSON`'s just a compatibility wrapper. You can run and test it while the installation process goes its way through the institutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I don't know about the json and json module, but simple code give the output what you expect.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
open('data',"file");
$/ = "}";
my @ar  = <data>;
foreach (@ar){
my @xz = split("\n",$_);
my @ddta;
foreach my $v (@xz){
my @xvz = split(/.*\:(.*)/,$v);
push(@ddta,@xvz);
}
print "@ddta\n\n";
}
```

Your data separated by the `{` so i'm use `$/ = "}"`. which   separated the data into array. Try it `print $ar[0]`.

Then `split(/.*\:(.*)/,$v)` which group the adjacent of the `:` so your expected output was stored into `@xvz` then will print out side of the inner foreach condtion